# Convert all columns to character except integer, posixct and Numeric

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 100 columns, is there a way to convert all columns to the character except for the columns that are integer, numeric and Posixct?

Wanted to check if this is possible?

Sample below. I have added 2 new columns to iris for demo purpose. Can anyone help me.

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ New1        : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 
 $ New2        : Posixct .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is.numeric` test for numeric as well as integers.

In `dplyr`, you can use `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate_if(~!(is.numeric(.) | is.POSIXct(.)), as.character)
```

Or in base R using `lapply`.

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) 
            if(is.numeric(x) | is.POSIXct(.)) x else as.character(x))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. But is.POSIXct(.)  is not there and hence throws error

Comment: @manishp Can you restart R and try again? It doesn't throw any error for me. For eg - `iris %>% mutate_if(~!(is.numeric(.) | is.POSIXct(.)), as.character)` Or `mtcars %>% mutate_if(~!(is.numeric(.) | is.POSIXct(.)), as.character)` both of them do not have any `POSIXct` column.

Answer (score 0):

We can create an index with `sapply`

```
 i1 <- !sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x)|is.POSIXct(x))
 data[i1] <- lapply(data[i1], as.character)
```